# Suspicious ISO file received by mail

Tags: email, iso-image

I have received a mail from a company `.com.jo` pretending it was a DHL notice.
It was clearly not as the `pdf` file had in fact an `.iso` extension.

As far as I know, such files are system images, so that launching it can practically replace your system.

I wonder, however, what would happen if I double click on it.  Would it automatically start?  Is it a new type of threat?  So far, I haven't found information about such files.

Comment: Most archive programs can extract an ISO, the dangers of extracting a malicious archive file are well known.  **Don't attempt to open the archive.**  Just delete the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ISO file is a whole disk image, but it is not *necessarily* self-executing. It is treated by the OS and software as an archive, much like ZIP or TAR files.

It *is possible* that this file is a [Zip (well, ISO) bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), relying on flaws in an archiver such as Windows built-in ISO viewer or 7-Zip to crash the system.

It is *also possible* that the file contains [password-protected malware](https://blog.appriver.com/2014/06/password-protected-malware) -- by using a password, the file cannot be evaluated by antimalware tools.

Since it arrived in an obvious phishing attack, handle with care, of course.

Comment: Actually, it is *never* self-executing. Autorun was disabled years ago, for good reasons. You’d have to confirm explicitly that you want to launch an autorun application, if present.

Comment: In my case, I haven't seen any password in the message but it has not been detected as an infected message by my Bitdefender software.

Answer (score 0):

"if I double click on it. Would it automatically start?"

It could, never double click unknown files.

Open it with a compression [utility like 7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html), this will show the contents of the iso without any danger. You can even extract portions of the iso (if it is actually an iso) if you wish.